# How to enable simultaneous access to lotus notes on a multi user VM?

Tags: virtual-machine, windows-server-2008-r2, lotus-notes

I have a multi user Virtual machine which has a Windows Server 2008 R2 as an Operating System. I have installed lotus notes on the VM. We have a notes .nsf database on the server and a local copy on the VM.

Firstly, it only allows one user to login into lotus notes even though it is a multi-user VM that allows upto 2 simultaneous access. Can i change the settings so that if 2 people logged in at the same time can use lotus notes on both the end?

Secondly, I want to isolate the local copy of the database. In the current case there is only one copy for all the users. I am want to make this as a single local copy for each user, can we?

Client Lotus Notes 8.5

Comment: Did you do the multi user install of the client, where each user's data is under their own profile?

Answer (score 1):

Without Citrix/Terminal Server you cannot use a VM with 2 different users at the same time.
The notes client canno't be startet multiple times in a regular vm even if it is a multiuser installation. It has to be installed for terminal server/citrix.

If you just want that 2 or more users can utilize the vm (not at the same time) you have to install the notes client as multi user (see admin help for that). 
Each user than must have its own login. Notes will autmatically install it's data directory into the users windows profile.

Answer (score 0):

You need a Lotus Domino Server to share simultaneous access to an NSF file. When a Lotus Notes client directly accesses an NSF, it gets an exclusive lock on the file. It doesn't matter whether you are talking about two real computers accessing the same file on a file server, or whether you are talking about two VMs access a shared disk drive, the result is the same: the first one will lock the second one out. The Domino server exists to manage shared access to NSF files.

If you have an existing Lotus Domino Server in your organization that can host the NSF file, you need to give the NSF file to the administrator and ask that s/he deploy it on your server and set up the ACL so that your users can get to it.

It not, then:

- You need to install another VM with Win 2008 R2 (or any other OS that
  IBM supports the Lotus Domino server form)
- You need to obtain a Lotus Domino license.
- You need to install and set up the Lotus Domino Server software on the Win 2008 R2 server.